# Get continuous scroll events in iOS Chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, safari

In Safari Mobile on iOS <8, all Javascript was paused while the user was scrolling. Since the release of iOS 8, this is no longer the case, as you can read here:

http://developer.telerik.com/featured/scroll-event-change-ios-8-big-deal/

This is great news. Executing Javascript while scrolling (if done right), opens the possibility for many usability enhancements (like sticky menus) and effects (like parallax).

**Is there a way to get the same thing in Chrome Mobile on iOS?**

The same website states that the first mobile browser that supported live `scroll` events was Chrome on Android 4.0. If that's the case, why is it still disabled in the newest Chrome on iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be the answer:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423444

If the new Javascript handling is tied to the new Nitro Javascript Engine used in Safari Mobile (and in  `WKWebView`), then we will have continuous scroll events in Chrome Mobile as soon as they switch to use `WKWebView` instead of `UIWebView`.

**EDIT:** As of version `48.0.2564.87`, Chrome uses `WKWebView` on iOS, and continuous scroll events are working!